# how to configure Automated builds using the Source Tree?

Tags: git, build-automation, atlassian-sourcetree

We are using the Git/Source Tree as our source repository.Now we want to setup the automated builds periodically. Which are the best ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a continuous integration system, and there are many to choose from. Probably your top choices for iOS are:

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) - free, a little complex to use
- [Travis-CI](http://travis-ci.org/) - free for open source projects, otherwise [paid](http://travis-ci.com/plans).
- [Xcode Bots](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW1) - free, comes with Mac OS X Server (free for developers), built by Apple

You'll likely want to install one of these pieces of software on a dedicated server (although Travis is hosted for you, as far as I'm aware). They can all monitor your Git repository and perform a new build whenever you push a commit.

Comment: But the Codebase is in C# developed using Xamarin.iOS,will this XCode bots works for me?

Comment: Probably not - Xcode Bots runs on a Mac server, and builds an iOS project as you would in Xcode. It won't know how to build a C# Xamarin project.

Comment: So what can be the best way of setting up the automated builds periodically?